# Arguments in main() ignored when debugging in Visual C++

Tags: c, debugging, program-entry-point, argv, argc

Up to this point I've been able to correctly view the output of my C codes by using the debugging command in Visual C++. However, when the script relies on parameters in the main function (eg/ `argc`, `argv`), the debugger seems to ignore both parameters and treat them as though they are uninitialized.

For instance, in the following code, the output is always `printf("Usage: find pattern\n");`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char *line, int max);

/* find: print lines that match pattern from 1st arg */
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int found = 0;

    if (argc != 2)
        printf("Usage: find pattern\n");
    else
        while (getline(line, MAXLINE) > 0)
            if (strstr(line, argv[1]) != NULL) {
                printf("%s", line);
                found++;
            }
    system("Pause");
    return found;
}

int getline(char *s, int lim)
{
    int c;
    char *i = s;

    while (--lim > 0 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        *s++ = c;
    if (c == '\n')
        *s++ = c;
    *s = '\0';
    return s-i;
}
```

How can I run the code such that argc and argv get used? Should I perhaps be using an IDE other than Visual C++?

Comment: In your project properties, you can specify command-line arguments to start your process with.  The exact instructions might depend on which version of Visual Studio you're using.

Comment: Yes definitely, you should quit using Visual C++,its an absolute crap.

Comment: What IDE would you recommend?

Comment: I do not agree with PHlfounder.  There is nothing wrong with the VS IDE.  It's not as if this particular problem is specific to VS; in *any* IDE that launches a process for you, at some point you're going to need to specify somewhere what you want your command-line arguments to be.

Comment: Damn, I'm seeing the same problem in VS 2013. I guess command-line debugging just isn't that important anymore.